# sort custom gridview ASC and DESC

Tags: c#, asp.net, sorting, gridview

I have a custom gridview. the code as below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"  GridLines="None" Width="768px" CellPadding="4" ForeColor="#333333" AllowPaging="True" PageSize="20" OnPageIndexChanging="gridView_PageIndexChanging" AllowSorting="true" OnSorting="gridViewSorting">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" />
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="User ID" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="33%" SortExpression="USERID" > 
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click" Text='<%#Eval("USERID") %>' runat="server"> 
                    <asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>    
            <asp:BoundField DataField="USERNAME" HeaderText="User Name" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="33%">  
            </asp:BoundField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="USERPOSITION" HeaderText="User Position" HeaderStyle-HorizontalAlign="Left" HeaderStyle-Width="33%"> 
            </asp:BoundField>
        </Columns>
    <PagerSettings  Mode="Numeric" PageButtonCount="10"/>
    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="White" />
</asp:GridView>
```

I wish to do sorting in this gridview but due to it is template field and datafield, therefore I couldn't use the default function in asp.net

I using backend code to do sorting but it is seem not working.

backend code for sorting as below

```
protected void gridViewSorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataTable = GridView1.DataSource as DataTable;

    if (dataTable != null)
    {
         DataView dataView = new DataView(dataTable);
         dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + "USERID ASC"; 
         GridView1.DataSource = dataView;
         GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I have tried several method and refer to few resources, it is still working

your comment and suggestion is much appreciated!!

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to sort by just UserID, you can remove it from sortexpression and just append the sorting direction.

```
dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " ASC";
```